# System.InvalidOperationException: ParseExact((({document}{CreationDate} + " ") + "00:00:00"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", ) is not supported

Tags: .net, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query

I tried to filter a mongoDb collection by date

HotelBookingDocument.cs

```
 public string CreationDate { get; set; }

// rest removed
```

```
    public IMongoCollection<HotelBookingDocument> HotelBookingCollection { get; set; }
```

```
// string Start, string End // inputs

        DateTime startDate;
        DateTime endDate;

        var query = new List<HotelBookingDocument>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Start) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(End))
        {
            startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Start + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  // works fine
            endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(End + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   // works fine

            query = await HotelBookingCollection.Find(s => (
                         startDate <= DateTime.ParseExact(s.CreationDate + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                          && DateTime.ParseExact(s.CreationDate + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= endDate)
                         ).ToListAsync();
        }  // errors occurs in this line
```

I got below error

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: ParseExact((({document}{CreationDate} + " ") + "00:00:00"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", ) is not supported.

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression expression)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(Expression variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression constantExpression)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateAndAlso(BinaryExpression node)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateWhere(WhereExpression node)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression node)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslatePipeline(PipelineExpression node)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression node)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry, ExpressionTranslationOptions translationOptions)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Translate(Expression expression)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Execute(Expression expression)

at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.MongoQueryableImpl`2.GetEnumerator()
         at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: see https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/frequently_encountered_issues/